# Execute .sh (bash scripts) file via "/bin/bash" in Linux with .NET Core

Tags: c#, linux, bash, .net-core

**OS**: Linux 4.15.0-48-generic #51-Ubuntu
**Framework**: .NET Core 4.6.27817.03

I have following `sample.sh` file below in :

```
 #!/bin/bash
 netstat --tcp --listen --numeric-ports -p
```

And following function to execute this file:

```
string filePathExecute = "./Assets/SystemTests/sample.sh";
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePathExecute);
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
startInfo.Arguments = $"\"{fileInfo.FullName}\"";
Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

But I am getting following output:

```
xdg-open: unexpected argument '/home/{filePathHere}/Assets/SystemTests/sample.sh'
Try 'xdg-open --help' for more information.
```

How can I make my application open a new terminal window and run `sample.sh` in it?

Comment: What is the actual version of .NET Core? 3.0 hasn't been released yet, so 4.6 is impossible.

Comment: NET Core 2.2.6 (CoreCLR 4.6.27817.03, CoreFX 4.6.27818.02)

Answer (score 0):

A classic finding solution after 10 minutes of trial happened.
Not sure why but after following flag, it started to work:

```
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

I don't do this on Windows while running powershell.ps1 files. 
Also this methods does not open a new window yet, runs on same windows, but for now it works now.

Comment: Watch out! UseShellExecute has changed meanings in .NET Core at different points in time: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24704. Just like Windows, UseShellExecute says "open this file/document in a new window" and xdg-open (the backend on Linux) has no idea how to handle `.sh` files here (should it open them? execute them? bring up a text editor?).

Comment: Yea, it does not run exactly the way I was expecting, but for now, I will live with that. I am not doing very fancy/dangerous things other than running some basic Linux Admin commands.

Comment: For what it's worth: Most of the APIs in .NET Core that talk about opening a new window are a no-op on Linux. There's no support in .NET Core (on Linux) to open new windows. The value of `CreateNoWindow` is never used.

Comment: It opens a new window in Windows 10 (at least for powershell & cmd), but no luck on Linux.